# How would you prevent someone calling a public mint function?

Tags: solidity, web3js, security

Sorry if this question is silly, I'm still learning.

My smart contract has a function which mints a token and is owned by the caller. I set it as public so it can be called externally through web3js. My game calls this mint function every time you beat a level. However, because it is a public function, is it true that someone can simply call this function without beating the game?

Answer (score 2):

I recommend you read OpenZeppelin's article on [Access Control](https://docs.openzeppelin.com/contracts/2.x/access-control) in Solidity.

In your case, you would inherit from [Ownable.sol](https://github.com/OpenZeppelin/openzeppelin-contracts/blob/v4.3.2/contracts/access/Ownable.sol) and add the `onlyOwnable` modifier to the `mint` function. Here's an [example](https://github.com/paulrberg/prb-proxy/blob/e260e1eb475e912ea98ba13cb81e9fd876f7c65a/contracts/PRBProxy.sol#L79-L81) for one of my contracts which does that:

```
function setMinGasReserve(uint256 newMinGasReserve) external override onlyOwner {
    minGasReserve = newMinGasReserve;
}
```